# How to get size of default textLabel inside UITableViewCell in iOS?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I try to add a secondary (custom) label below the default textLabel of UITableViewCell.

I want to set the frame correctly which should really be below the textLabel. However, all values return 0, so I can't prepare the frame of the custom view correctly.

in

`- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

`NSLog(@"%f, %f, %f, %f", cell.textLabel.frame.origin.x,cell.textLabel.frame.origin.y,cell.textLabel.frame.size.height,cell.textLabel.frame.size.width);`

prints

`0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000`

How can I get the correct x and y for my custom secondary description view? (I know that UITableViewCell has a template similar to this one but I don't want to use detail view template)

Comment: Add Two custom labels inplace of default cell.textlabel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default size is **[cell labelsize = 15 0 43.5 270]**

You will not get size of textLabel when cell=nil. Drag your tableview upside & then check the logs. You will find these values.

But if you wants two labels then use this code. It's simple.

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        UITableViewCell *cell =[ tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
        UILabel * invoiceTitle;
        UILabel * projectTitle;

        if(cell==nil)
        {
            cell=[[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"]autorelease];

            invoiceTitle     = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(14, 0, cell.contentView.frame.size.width, cell.contentView.frame.size.height/2)];
            [invoiceTitle setTag:111];
            [cell.contentView addSubview:invoiceTitle];
            [invoiceTitle release];

            projectTitle     = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(14, cell.contentView.frame.size.height/2 + 1, cell.contentView.frame.size.width - cell.contentView.frame.size.height/2];
            [projectTitle setTag:222];
            [cell.contentView addSubview:projectTitle];
            [projectTitle release];
        }
        else
        {

            invoiceTitle = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:111];
            projectTitle = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:222];
        }

        [projectTitle setText:LOCAL(@"Title1")];
        [invoiceTitle setText:@"Title2"];

        return cell;
    }
```

Happy coding...

Comment: I try to get textLabel's size after allocating and setting the "cell". It does not give the size.. So you mean that I have to completely give up using default textLabel and "also" replace it with a custom primary label. Right?

Comment: Exactly, i did in many projects. It is the good way to do custom things. Because using default textLabel will make your things worse sometimes. Like wrapping one label over another etc etc.. Please accept answer if it helped you.

Comment: Default size of textLabel of default UITableViewCell is correct, but for iOS 7 only. On iOS 6 width of textLabel is 280, and origin.x is 15. You need take precautions coding for both iOS 7 and earlier.

Answer (score 1):

You may very likely not get the sizes in the cell immediately after load. Initially `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` will give you zero values. You must either scroll out of view or call `[tableView reload]` method somehow. This will call `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` again with new values. The origins of the frames will be different but the sizes should be the same. I used this technique to get sizes of detailTextLabel.frame. Here is my example and how I got the sizes:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    ......
    NSLog(@“detailCell frame is %@”, NSStringFromCGRect(cell.detailTextLabel.frame));
    ......
}
```

Good luck